# Runtime exception in syntax like defining two vals with identical names

Tags: scala, syntax

In some book I've got a code similar to this:

```
object ValVarsSamples extends App {

  val pattern = "([ 0-9] +) ([ A-Za-z] +)". r   // RegEx

  val pattern( count, fruit) = "100 Bananas"
}
```

This is supposed to be a trick, it should like defining same names for two vals, but it is not.

So, this fails with an exception.

The question: *what this might be about? (what's that supposed to be?) and why it does not work?*

--
As I understand first: val pattern - refers to RegEx constructor function.. And in second val we are trying to pass the params using such a syntax? just putting a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extractor:

```
val pattern( count, fruit) = "100 Bananas"
```

This code is equivalent

```
val res = pattern.unapplySeq("100 Bananas")
count = res.get(0)
fruit = res.get(1)
```

Comment: What I'm not comfortable with is: "val" it looks very much as if I define a new value. When unapply happens in match-case, then it's ok

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your regex doesn't match, you should change it to:

```
val pattern = "([ 0-9]+) ([ A-Za-z]+)". r
```

The space before + in `[ A-Za-z] +` means you are matching a single character in the class `[ A-Za-z]` and then at least one space character. You have the same issue with `[ 0-9] +`.

Scala regexes define an extractor, which returns a sequence of matching groups in the regular expression. Your regex defines two groups so if the match succeeds the sequence will contain two elements.

Comment: ah.. even to this: "([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+)". Deleted spaces.. Ok.
Could you explain the syntax of such a val-repeating.?